Issues defining cross-origin policies to allow both WASM and popups
I have an app that relies on WASM, and SharedArrayBuffer requires to define the following headers:



Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy same-origin



However I also have popups + images from S3 in my website, that only work when defining


Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin-allow-popups



This is very frustrating because I cannot get my WASM to work without breaking my popups, and Vice Versa. Anyone have a solution for this?
